# why can't I get gdm  to stop?

Tags: gdm

im been trying to stop this x-server here on ubuntu 10.04.
i have done:

`sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop`  (doesnt do anything really)

`sudo service gdm stop`      (stop: unknown instance)

`sudo stop gdm`              (stop: unknown instance)

this is driving me crazy... i cant seem to find anything else to stop it, and i cant find if its a bug or not.

`sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop`  (only stats that i should do "sudo service gdm stop:)

this is all from the CTRL + ALT + F1 virtual interface some call it. (a command line)

i have been on this for days (3), i really need advise please!!

Comment: What do you have as output of `pgrep -fl X`?

Comment: 1126 /usr/bin/X :0 -nr -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-dLyIhI/database -nolisten tcp vt7

Comment: oh my gosh it worked, sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop                 i opened terminal then this command the black screen then CTRL + ALT + F1. i have to have the gui up to run it

Comment: thought we covered this

Comment: you never told me that i run the command before pressing CTRL + ALT +F1. so i have been doing it like the tutorial says to do it. they had same command as you.

Comment: my fault for thinking you knew that

Comment: i didnt thats why i look for help. only way i was told from tutorials is to go into CTRL + ALT + F1 first. i was recording the terminal to show how it doesnt work but it worked. i got lucky.

Comment: @Alex If you have solved the problem, can you please add it as an answer to this question? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

OK i experienced that you run the command below before you go into CTRL + ALT + F1. if you run if afterwards. it will just advise you to run a different command.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop
```

I was running this command to install Nvidia drivers manually.